# How to output Select Statement inside oracle Begin- End

Tags: oracle

basically  i am from MS SQL background but the situation is that i need to create a query in Oracle that has a temp table and inside Begin - End i m updating that table's row and at the end i want a select Statement to output that table.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_users ( 
   id number(5)  NOT NULL, 
   name varchar2(50)  NOT NULL, 
   surname varchar2(50)  NOT NULL ) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

Declare  
dd varchar(400); 
Begin 




    INSERT INTO temp_users VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith'); 
    INSERT INTO temp_users VALUES (2, 'Anne', 'Parker'); 
    INSERT INTO temp_users VALUES (3, 'Kate', 'Doe'); 
    INSERT INTO temp_users VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith'); 
    INSERT INTO temp_users VALUES (2, 'Anne', 'Parker'); 
    INSERT INTO temp_users VALUES (3, 'Kate', 'Doe'); 



    // this code i have used to return the table
     execute immediate'SELECT * FROM temp_users'; 



     execute immediate 'drop table temp_users'; 

End;
```

Comment: Why do you want to run the select within begin end? Oracle's procedure doesn't necessarily follow the same practices as in MSSQL. Tell us why do you want it to run within begin..end, we'll give you a better solution. Also, let us know which version of Oracle you're running.

Comment: to get/return the data back so that i can use it some where else.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, you can either simply return everything using `bulk collect into` clause, like in this [Oracle example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm#CJAJAAIG) and return it outside.

Or you can use `PIPELINED` clause, in which case you create a cursor and pipe it outside like:

```sql
FUNCTION some_fn
(
  in_1 IN NUMBER,
  in_2 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
)
RETURN some_table_type PIPELINED
[…]
FOR l_row IN c_some_cursor
      LOOP
        PIPE ROW(l_row);
 END LOOP;
```

In both cases you should declare table variable **TYPE** like [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/PLS23/ch4.htm). Your function should (because function is probably what would suit you best) return that table variable type.